# Boto3: List objects of a specific S3 folder in python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to get the list of objects within a specific S3 location like: `bucket_name/my_location`

Before, I used to have a code which would work for the whole bucket:

```
from boto3 import resource
# S3 connection
s3_connection = resource(service_name = 's3',
                         aws_access_key_id = s3_key,
                         aws_secret_access_key = s3_secret)
# S3 bucket
s3_bucket_connection = s3_connection.Bucket(s3_bucket)
for my_obj in s3_bucket_connection.objects.all():
    print(my_obj)
```

But my access and secret keys do not have the permission to list all folders and are set to have access only to a folder called `my_location`. I have already tried:

```
s3_bucket_connection = s3_connection.Bucket(s3_bucket + '/my_location')
```

which does not work and throws an exception about bucket name not being formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```py
s3_bucket_connection.objects.all():
```

with:

```py
s3_bucket_connection.objects.filter(Prefix='my_location/):
```